# Update a specific column value using a php snippet in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to retrieve the distinct post_title values from the wp_posts table and then to update the post_name column with the urlencoded post_title values.

I tried the following php code:

```
<?php
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts" );
        foreach ( $result as $wpposts )   {
            $wp_temp = $wpposts->post_title;
        $wp_title = urlencode($wp_temp);
          mysql_query("UPDATE wp_posts SET post_name = '" . $wp_title . "'  WHERE post_title != NULL") or die(mysql_error());  
            }
      ?>
```

However, I got the following error message:

> Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in
>   /hermes/xxxxxxxxxxx/b1890/.../page-temp.php on line 19 Warning:
>   mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in
>   /hermes/xxxxxxxxxxx/b1890/.../page-temp.php
>   on line 19 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

How can I make it done?
In addition, is there a way to select only distinct post_tile rows only?

Thanks.